# 12c connection lost some times

Tags: .net, oracle

After upgrading Oracle to 12c my exe starts to crash after some time. it can connect and can do its DB jobs successfully and then suddenly stops. I searched google and this site but generally, those problems are with creating a connection, while my problem is termination of the connection after a while.

**Event logs:**

```
Application: MyRunner.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.Net.Sockets.SocketException
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(Byte[], Int32, Int32, System.Net.Sockets.SocketFlags)
   at OracleInternal.Network.ReaderStream.Read(OracleInternal.Network.OraBuf)

Exception Info: OracleInternal.Network.NetworkException
   at OracleInternal.Network.ReaderStream.Read(OracleInternal.Network.OraBuf)
   at OracleInternal.TTC.OraBufReader.GetDataFromNetwork()
   at OracleInternal.TTC.OraBufReader.Read(Boolean)
   at OracleInternal.TTC.TTCExecuteSql.ReceiveExecuteResponse(OracleInternal.TTC.Accessors.Accessor[] ByRef, OracleInternal.TTC.Accessors.Accessor[], Boolean, OracleInternal.Common.SQLMetaData ByRef, OracleInternal.Common.SqlStatementType, Int64, Int32, Int32 ByRef, Int64 ByRef, Int32, Int32, Int64[], Boolean ByRef, OracleInternal.ServiceObjects.DataUnmarshaller ByRef, MarshalBindParameterValueHelper ByRef, Boolean, Boolean ByRef)

Exception Info: Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleException
   at Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleException.HandleError(OracleInternal.Common.OracleTraceLevel, OracleInternal.Common.OracleTraceTag, System.Exception)
   at OracleInternal.TTC.TTCExecuteSql.ReceiveExecuteResponse(OracleInternal.TTC.Accessors.Accessor[] ByRef, OracleInternal.TTC.Accessors.Accessor[], Boolean, OracleInternal.Common.SQLMetaData ByRef, OracleInternal.Common.SqlStatementType, Int64, Int32, Int32 ByRef, Int64 ByRef, Int32, Int32, Int64[], Boolean ByRef, OracleInternal.ServiceObjects.DataUnmarshaller ByRef, MarshalBindParameterValueHelper ByRef, Boolean, Boolean ByRef)
   at OracleInternal.ServiceObjects.OracleCommandImpl.ExecuteNonQuery(System.String, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleParameterCollection, System.Data.CommandType, OracleInternal.ServiceObjects.OracleConnectionImpl, Int32, Int32, OracleInternal.ServiceObjects.OracleDependencyImpl, Int64[] ByRef, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleParameterCollection ByRef, Boolean ByRef, Boolean)
   at Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

**How can I stop my exe from crashing after a period of time?**

Comment: The exception message points to an error while reading the data response from the server. I would check the database or the network. Maybe the server is getting too many connections and droping requests? Are you disposing ine your database acceses? Its hard to help only with the error message.

Comment: thanks @bradbury9 , i could not identify actual problem but  i changed the service recovery settings to restart when fail, since then it hasnt stopped, there is no failure logs in event logs.